# MATLAB/Simulink R2019b Derivative Block is Linearized to Zero

Tags: matlab, simulink, linearization

I'm trying to linearize a model with an output that is dependent on the derivative of a signal. The derivative block has the following diagnostic message in the linearization advisor:

Derivative block is linearized to zero when Linearization Time is set to Inf. Please consider using a finite number for the Linearization Time parameter.

My system is time-continuous, so I have the 'SampleTime' option set to 0, but this doesn't seem to be what the diagnostic is referring to. I've tried both model trimming, and linearizing about a time where the model has reached steady state, but this message appears in each case. I've also tried using the 'Switched derivative for linearization' block, but this doesn't seem to have fixed it either.

I can't find any other documentation referring to this linearization time parameter. How can I change it and what is its meaning?